# Notification wakes up IOS and ANDROID app in xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have application written in Xamarin that uses firebase.

Imagine both apps( iOS and android) are killed and our phone is locked. Notification comes to the app ( iOS and android ) and I want to wake up one screen from my Xamarin app ( somebody is calling my app so it behaves like skype).

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

For Xamarin.Android, you can check this document: [Starting an Activity from a Notification](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/local_notifications_in_android/#Starting_an_Activity_from_a_Notification).

Important is that you need to `SetContentIntent` to the activity which handles your notification when you build it.

For Xamarin.iOS, please refer to the `Responding to Notifications and Events` part of [this doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:).

For Xamarin.Forms, you may need to use [DependencyService](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction/) to implement notification on each platform.